# How to export gridview data in PDF by using scryber in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf-generation

Here i want to save the data in DB and that data will be shown in Gridview.when i want to press the Button the gridview data will be append to PDF by using SCRYBER
Here my code it is just how to display the simple textbox data only    (Here i dont use ITEXTSHARP)
amespaces.

```
protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PDFDocument doc = new PDFDocument();
    PDFPage page = new PDFPage();
    page.PaperSize = Scryber.PaperSize.A4;
    page.PaperOrientation = Scryber.PaperOrientation.Portrait;
    doc.Pages.Add(page);
    PDFImage img = new PDFImage();
    img.Source="img source";
    PDFLabel lbl = new PDFLabel();
    lbl.Text = "Name:";
    lbl.FontSize = 14;
    PDFTextLiteral tl = new PDFTextLiteral();
    tl.Text = txt1.Text;
    tl.FontSize = 14;
    page.Contents.Add(img);
    page.Contents.Add(lbl);
    page.Contents.Add(tl);
    doc.ProcessDocument(this.Response);
}
```

Comment: so where is question ? what is problem in it, please specify clearly

Comment: i want to store that textbox value in db and retrived in Gridview.that gridview data will be export in PDF